# mysql on Azure check if database exist and respond with message c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, azure, visual-studio

so I have a function that tried to create a new database, and I want to return a message if it already existed or not.

```
          using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS main", conn))
                {
                    // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
                    var numberOfActions = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    responseMessage = numberOfActions != 0 ? "ok, main database created" : "main already existed, no changes were made";
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
```

But I always get the true value for the bool ("ok, main database created"), why ? how can I solve this?.

Comment: What is the result you are getting in numberOfActions ?

Comment: As per the code it means , If it return value 0, then database already exists, else database will be created.

Comment: I don't think RowsAffected applies to CREATE statements. You should be getting -1 regardless of the outcome of the statement.

Comment: Based on the output of numberofActions , need to change the logic. What is the output you are getting in numberofActions ?

Comment: Hey, numberofActions giving me 1

Comment: @ILovePizza are you sure its not -1?

Comment: Check if database is really created ?If it is created , delete the DB and again run the Code and check the numberofActions.

Comment: @ILovePizza - Still you are having the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

IF you call **ExecuteNonQueryAsync** your code will continue execution and you can track when the actual call to `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` completes via the `Task<int>` object that it returns.

Here is the workaround to fix your issue.

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS main", conn))
{
    // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
    // skip this 
    // var numberOfActions = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    
    object numberOfActions = await cmd. ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    int objID = 0;
    
    if(numberOfActions != null)
    {
        int.TryParse(numberOfActions.ToString(), out objID);
    }
    
    // objID is greater than 0 means Main database created if not the Main database already available
    responseMessage = (objID > 0) ? "ok, main database created" : "main already existed, no changes were made";
    }
}
return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
```